# Matlab recursion: inefficient code or complex recursion?

Tags: matlab, recursion, time, execution, coding-efficiency

I am struggling to get the solution of this recursion problem in reasonable execution times.

Here, I show the recursive function which basically computes the coefficients of a polynomial.

```
function [ coeff ] = get_coeff( n, k, tau, x )

if(n == 0) % 1st exit condition
    coeff = 0;
else
    if(k == 0) % 2nd exit condition
        coeff = max(0, n*tau-x)^n;
    else % Else recursion
        total = 0;
        for l = k-1:n-2
            total = total + nchoosek(l, k-1)*tau^(l-k+1)*get_coeff(n-1, l, tau, x);
        end
        coeff = (n/k) * total;            
    end
end

end

 % This symbolic summation solution gives numerical errors, probably due to rounding
 % effects.
 %           syms l;
 %           f = nchoosek(l, k-1)*tau^(l-k+1)*get_coeff(n-1, l, tau, x);
 %           coeff = (n/k) * symsum(f, l, k-1, n-2);
```

And this is the main script where I make use of the recursive function:

```
Tau = 1;
ns = [3];
%delays = 0:0.25:8;
delays = [0];
F_x = zeros(1, size(delays, 2));
rho = 0.95;
tic
for ns_index = 1: size(ns, 2)

  T = Tau*(ns(ns_index)+1)/rho;

  % Iterate delays (x)
  for delay_index = 1:size(delays, 2)
     total = 0;

     % Iterate polynomial.
     for l = 0:ns(ns_index)-1
        total = total + get_coeff(ns(ns_index), l, Tau, delays(delay_index))*(T - ns(ns_index)*Tau + delays(delay_index))^l;
     end

    F_x(1, delay_index) = T^(-ns(ns_index))*total;

  end

end
toc
```

I've simplified, "ns" and "delays" vectors to contain a single value so that it is easier to follow. In summary, for a fixed value of "ns", I need to compute all the coefficients of the polynomial using the recursive function and compute its final value at "delays". By increasing the number of points in "delays", I can see a curve for a fixed "ns".
My question is: for any "ns" between 1 and 10, the computation is really fast, in the order of 0.069356 seconds (even for the whole "delays" vector). Conversely, for ns = [15] or [20], the computation time increases A LOT (I didn't even manage to see the result). 
I'm not keen on assessing computational complexity, so I don't know if there is a problem in my code (maybe nchoosek function?, or for loops?) or maybe it is the way it has to be having in mind this recursion problem.

EDIT:
I see it is indeed the factorial growth of the amount of calculations, as Adriaan stated. Do you think that any kind of approximation of `nchoosek` could be useful to tackle this problem? Something like: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation](http://Do%20you%20think%20the%20Striling's%20approximation%20would%20be%20useful%20to%20reduce%20the%20execution%20time?%20en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

[The last formula in this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1094425/) is what I'm trying to implement (note I changed delta for tau):

[image]

Comment: Can you give the formula of the polynomial coefficients? Maybe the computation can be done some way other than recursively

Comment: Elaborating: `15! = 1.3077e+12`, so if that's the amount of calculations, of course it'll take a long time, even if the calculation time is around a microsecond for a single iteration. In contrast: `12! = 4.8e8`, which is 10,000 times less, so I'm not very surprised it takes a very long time for `ns>15`

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula of the polynomial coefficients is that one. So it is recursive by definition.

Comment: Do you think the Striling's approximation would be useful to reduce the execution time? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: As a solution sketch: it's recursive, no need to calculate `ns!` times. Calculate the first point, the second from that etc, store when done, then multiply by the correct prefactor (that division in front of the summation) and that should be it. I'm not sure why your code has a factorial growth in iterations, but there shouldn't be.

Comment: Isn't that the same you discussed in the answer below? I can compute and store get_coeff(1, 0, tau, x) so that I don't need to compute it later but, anyway, I'll have to iterate through it whenever I want o compute (18) q_(n, l+1). The only difference now is that I'll extract the result from a matrix, but I am not reducing the number of iterations, right? And for sure, the code doesn't have has a factorial growth in iterations, becuase I computed ns=15 in about 1 hour.

Comment: You can create two matrices of size `[ns+1 x ns+1]` and store precomputed results of   `nchoosek` and `get_coeff` into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally managed to compute the coefficients in a reasonable amount of time. Basically, I took the suggestions from Adriaan and rahnema1 and created a ns by ns matrix to store all the coefficients that I compute in a recursive way. Therefore, when a certain leaf of the recursive tree is repeated I am able to prune the tree by extracting the value from the matrix. Note that the gain is not based on precomputing the values (since I compute them on the go) but on pruning the number of recursions. Here you have some numbers:

- **ns = 10 ; delay = 0**: the number of calls to the old recursive function was 23713. Now, this is solved in 175 calls.
- **For ns = 10; delay = [0:0.25:8]**: 782529 calls with the old function and 2.74 seconds of execution time, 495 to the new one and 0.02 which is ~ 125x times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the profile on your code, and I get this:

[image: Profiler result]

I looks like most of the time is spent with nchoosek, who takes two integers as input. You could try precalculating the needed value and storing them in a matrix for quicker access!

---

Edit: I tried precalculating nchoosek as such:

```
for i = 0 : ns
    for j = 0 : ns
        if j < i
            nchoosek_(i+1,j+1) = nchoosek(i,j);
        else
            nchoosek_(i+1,j+1) = NaN;
        end
    end
end
```

And then within the function:

```
total = total + nchoosek_(l+1, k-1+1)*tau^(l-k+1)*get_coeff(n-1, l, tau, x , nchoosek_);
```

It seems to work, and I get a nice improvement with ns = 12:

[image: Profiler result with precalculation]

But I still hit the wall for ns = 15...

Comment: The `nchoosek` call disappeared in your second profile. Since you calculate it, albeit in advance, it should still be taken into account. Is it covered inside the `temp>get_coeff` now? 75% reduction is time is great for the lower values of `ns`, but, as I commented on the question, if I am correct the problem is the factorial growth of the amount of calculations, in which case a linear time reduction is not going to cut it (75% reduction on a year worth of calculation time still leaves you with 3 months)

Comment: I left out the initial loop to calculate nchoosek because its time is negligible and it will not scale with ns: 0.008s versus 1.041s within the function. I'll update the figure in the answer. However your calculation is the right answer: clearly the factorial makes the number of function calls explode rapidly!